# Cannot enable a button in jQuery when fields are autofilled in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have the following simple form in HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" /> Username
  <input type="password" name="password" /> Password
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

and in jQuery:

```
function verifySumbit(){
if(!$(":text").val().length || !$(":password").val().length) {
     $(":submit").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
     $(":submit").prop("disabled", false);
  }
}

$(function(){
   verifySubmit();

  $(":text, :password").on("keyup", function(){
     verifySubmit();
  });
});
```

Excellent, **until if you save user and password in Chrome dialog** and next time when you go to form, these fields are autofilled and button is disabled!

I made first input to be focused when document is ready:

```
$(":text").focus();
```

If you press F5 in browser then the button is enabled, but if you select address url and press enter on it OR duplicate tab, the button is disabled even the focus exists for first input.

Does it is Chrome bug or from me ?

Comment: I didn't test but it could be that chrome fills it on window load and not document ready, meaning when you validate it, it isn't filled in yet.

Comment: Your html is invalid, i assume you are not actually using this actual html.

Comment: @haxtbh: What part is invalid ??

Comment: Wouldn't call it invalid, you missed a *p* in the 2nd input (currently *inut*)

Comment: `<inut type="password" name="password" />` - I see you closed the last `"`  as this was missing too but the tag is still incorrect. It should be `input`.

Comment: Perhaps you are depending on some php code .... because when you select the url and press enter $_POST and $_GET variables are destructed so you can't use them

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC, not PHP